# Want to retrieve uint value in mapping after I deposited money into the payable function but instead of receiving deposited value, I receive 0. WHY?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract EtherStore {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function withraw() public {
        uint bal = balances[msg.sender];
        require(bal > 0);

        (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: bal}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");

        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code for the deposit part. So I guess the issue is that you deposit or checked the balance incorrectly.

❌ WARNING: the withdrawal part can be hacked. DO NOT use this code. See more: "Reentrancy Attack" (https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/re-entrancy)

Comment: I used the code without the Reentrancy implement and after I deposited the ether I then went to view inside mapping function with the address linked to deposit as the key thinking the amount deposited would be stored in the mapping and I would be able to read it but I keep getting back 0